# lxml: Remove dummy namespace in output?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

I’m using lxml to generate a SVG. Consider the following code:

```
import lxml.etree as Etree

Root = Etree.Element("svg", nsmap={None: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                                   "xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"})
Link = Etree.SubElement(Root, 'a')
Link.set("{xlink}href", "#")
Etree.SubElement(Link, "text", y="12").text = "test"

print(Etree.tostring(Root, encoding="utf-8", pretty_print=True,
                     xml_declaration=True).decode("utf-8"))
```

This outputs

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <a xmlns:ns0="xlink" ns0:href="#">
    <text y="12">test</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Notice that lxml makes a “dummy” namespace `ns0` and put the `href` in it.  How do I let lxml get rid of it and just output `xlink:href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the correct namespace URI when adding the `xlink:href` attribute.

Change

```
Link.set("{xlink}href", "#")
```

to

```
Link.set("{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href", "#")
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I don't know why I didn't realize it…